# How to install .NET framework v4.0.30319 on wine?

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I wanted to install osu!, but it doesn't work when you go on PlayOnLinux (error message and nothing happens).

Then, I followed [this video on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VtDOGE7PjDA).

As the video showed (at 2:44,) I clicked on **Run a .exe file in this virtual drive** then I clicked on `osu!install.exe` and then I get this message:

[image: To run this application, you first must install one of the following versions of the .NET Framework: v4.0.30319]

Can you tell me how to install this?

Answer (score 5):

With `winetricks` and a 32-bit WINE prefix. Be in mind, that PlayOnLinux use a separate wine prefix for each installed applications. For this reason, you have to use *your* `WINEPREFIX`:

```
sudo apt-get install winetricks
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 winetricks dotnet40
```

---

**But** as you can read [here](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-1856-osu.html), the installation script for *osu*

```
Script is outdated and no longer works.
```

And couriosly, *osu* needs `dotnet20` and not `dotnet40`.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I think that the download is succesful but i got a error message: "Unhandled exception: unimplemented function mscoree.dll.CorIsLatestSvc called in 32-bit code (0x7b83aace).[...] "

Comment: Start again with a clean `wine` folder: `mv ~/.wine ~/.wine_bak`

Comment: Still no :(. Could you please give me the way to install .NET framework 4 from the begining step by step please. I have a 64bit-ubuntu, I think it's where the problem is.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: i found that 4.03 refers to that dotnet40_kb2468871. I have similar problem with Video strip poker Girls

Answer (score 1):

Try following the [Official Documentation on installing Osu!](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=9581) on the winetricks hq

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

i found that 4.03 refers to that dotnet40_kb2468871. I have similar problem with Video strip poker Girls. Not succeded to work the game but installed the
dotnet patch 4.03.

Solution 1:

Download NDP40-KB2468871-v2-x86.exe and/or NDP40-KB2468871-v2-x64.exe
from microsoft site. And install them with either wineprefix 32 or 64. They will be installed.

Solution 2: dotnet40_kb2468871 is available through winetricks.

Solution 3:
Copy paste: [1](https://github.com/mohamedemam223/winetricks/issues/274)

```
I've instaleled KB2468871 to current wine-stable (wine-2.0.3) and seems to work fine for me.
Here are the steps:

Ensure that you are using 32-bit env (export WINEARCH=win32) and install dotnet40 via winetricks (winetricks dotnet40) in a fresh x86 wine.
Run NDP40-KB2468871-v2-x86.exe
The window shows an error message ("KB2468871v2 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer."). Keep this window open.
Copy the directory generated by the installer to a new directory (setup, for example). The directory exists directly under C:\. For example, if the directory's name is e0118ff86cf108d878 then do cp -a .wine/drive_c/e0118ff86cf108d878 .wine/drive_c/setup .
Close the installer's window.
Install the patch directly by msiexec.exe. Running wine .wine/drive_c/windows/system32/msiexec.exe /p C:\\setup\\NDP40-KB2468871.msp would suffice.
```